# How do I set the whole rows background color in a C++ console app

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, codeblocks

How do I go about doing as mentioned in the subject line?

Below is a screenshot of my console app as well as some code.

[image]

```
switch (indicator) {
    case GreenFlag:
        indicator = GreenFlag;
        system("CLS");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_GREEN);
        cout << "IF YOUR CAR ISN'T LEAKING OIL AND YOU DON'T MAKE A NOISE YOU'RE WELCOME TO PARK HERE!" << endl << endl;
        break;
        ...
    default:
        system("CLS");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
        cout << "INCORRECT OPTION, PLEASE TRY AGAIN!" << endl << endl;
        break;
}
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
```

Comment: Would writing spaces work ? Then you just need to figure out the width

Comment: @Jeffrey that might work, but that's more of a hack than a viable solution for me to be honest.

Comment: OT, but you just described the whole of winapi ;-)

Comment: Hahaha good point :-).

Comment: The console is character-based. It doesn't have a notion of rows and columns. If your program needs that sort of higher-level information, you're going to have to use the [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) instead (like [FillConsoleOutputAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputattribute)). Entirely not future-proof, but there you have it. @jef Let's play a game: Name an API that has been ABI-compatible across decades. You win if you find one that's not the Windows API.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable I'm going to have to give this some more thought as to how I want to solve this issue, as I would prefer it to be future-proof.

Comment: *"Entirely not future-proof"* with the Window API means, that you will have to worry about your application failing in about roughly half of a century. Nothing wrong with opting in to [the future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). My comment just meant to illustrate, what *"history-preserving"* means to *some* (one) corporation. Regardless, if you're issuing `system("CLS")` calls, you're already living on borrowed time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I came up with in the end!

I think it's pretty solid, but it still needs quite a bit of work.

@IInspectable I'm still looking into the best approach to clear the screen so that it's future proof.

```
string message = "";
// Indicator mood;
// mood = (Indicator)Random.Range(0, System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Indicator)).Length);)

switch (indicator) {
    case GreenFlag:
        indicator = GreenFlag;
        // TODO: Need to replace system("CLS") with a more portable option, take a look at the following link(s):
        // https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/ and https://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/3304/ for more information!
        system("CLS");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_GREEN);
        message = "IF YOUR CAR ISN'T LEAKING OIL AND YOU DON'T MAKE A NOISE YOU'RE WELCOME TO PARK HERE!";
        cout << message.append(120 - message.length(), ' ') << endl << endl;
        break;
...
default:
        system("CLS");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
        message = "INCORRECT OPTION, PLEASE TRY AGAIN!";
        cout << message.append(120 - message.length(), ' ') << endl << endl;
        break;
}
```

Thanks again for the thoughts around this @Jeffrey and @IInspectable, appreciate the solid advice ;-).